# Qt Creator 3.0.1 + GDB 7.4 : debug doesn't work

Tags: linux, qt, gdb

On my Linux Mint 13, if I try to debug my Qt application, I see in the output:

```
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Invalid argument\n"
```

If I try to break execution, I see in the status line: `Stop requested...` , and after several seconds: `Attempting to interrupt`. That's it, nothing more.

I've seen some old questions related to similar issue, and I found the only answer [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26506-amp-quot-warning-GDB-Failed-to-set-controlling-terminal-Invalid-argument-n-quot?p=128125#post128125), but it doesn't work for me, unfortunately: I have created file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/Qt.conf` with the following contents:

```
# Qt libraries
/opt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc/lib
```

But nothing changed.

**UPD:** After Qt Creator restart, behavior changed a bit: now it stucks on the "Setting breakpoints..." stage, and after 40 seconds shows this message:

> The gdb process has not responded to a command within 40 second(s).
>   This could mean it is stuck in an endless loop or taking longer than
>   expected to perform the operation. You can choose between waiting
>   longer or aborting debugging.

I also upgraded gdb to latest 7.7: I installed `libncurses5-dev` package: `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev` , which is needed to build gdb.

I downloaded latest gz archive from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb to the temporary folder, and executed the following commands:

```
tar xvfz gdb-*.gz
cd gdb*
./configure
make
cp gdb/gdb /usr/local/bin
```

I also set up my Qt project to use gdb from /usr/local/bin . It is used now, but nothing is changed.

By the way, in Windows it works. How to solve it in Ubuntu 12.04 (Linux Mint 13)?